# How to set up httpClient with pfx certificate?

Tags: go, https, ssl-certificate, pfx, go-http

I am creating an application which will communicate with other systems via rest APIs with one .pfx certificate. I have to write this application in Go. Any leads will be extremely helpful.

Comment: you can extract `cert` [file from pfx file](https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/extract-the-public-certificate-and-private-key-from-a-pfx-file-using-openssl/), and then use `http.ListenAndServeTLS` https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution.